# How to get Unicode data with Django rest

Tags: python, django, unicode, django-rest-framework

I have web-service which should give data with GET requests, that data include Unicode.

My views:

```
class personsViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    render_classes = (JSONRenderer, )
    queryset = person.objects.all()
    serializer_class = personSerializer
```

my URLs:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^persons/', views.personsViewSet.as_view({'get':'list'})), 
]
```

I put in my REST_FRAMEWORK config

```
    'UNICODE_JSON': True,
```

and I'm still getting non Unicode data like:

```
"KeyWords":"ÐºÐ»ÑŽÑ‡ÐµÐ²Ð¾Ðµ ÑÐ»Ð¾Ð²Ð¾ 1"
```

Please help me with fixing it.

Comment: I meet a similar problem, but with httpie in terminal, I need to add --response-charset=utf8

Answer (score 0):

Either you're viewing your response with a non utf8 reader, either your initial data are messed.